# tweaked international mobile number format

Tags: regex

I need a pattern (java regex) that will match international mobile numbers containing 7 to 17 digits with the exception that the first 3 digits can not be (**965**) consecutively.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First (if necessary) remove all non-digits from your string, for example like this:

```
String sanitized_number = raw_number.replaceAll("\\D+", "");
```

Then check if the following is True:

```
boolean foundMatch = sanitized_number.matches("^(?!965)\\d{7,17}$");
```

Comment: +1 But don't you need the < for negative look-behind? As in `^(?<!965)\d{7,17}$`

Comment: I'm looking ahead, therefore `(?!...)`. No way to look behind at the start of a string :)

Comment: If you're matching international numbers, would you not allow a leading '+'?

Comment: @Marty: That `+` is removed in the first step, along with all other non-numbers. I think the requirements are too vague to tell whether that's a Good Thing or not...

Comment: @Tim: Thanks a lot. Its working.

@Marty: Yes, the numbers will have a leading '+' or '00'. And I'm gonna match it with '(\+|00)'.